# Define two orthogonal subspace of dimension $2$ for $\mathbb{R^4}$

Tags: linear-algebra

My question is that:

Could you provide an example of two orthogonal subspaces $V$ and $V^{\perp}$ of dimension $2$ for $\mathbb{R^4}$ ($V \cap  V^{\perp} = \{0\}$)?

Thanks.

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that two subspaces have in common at least the zero vector:
$V \cap  V^{\perp} = \{\vec 0\}$.

The subspace spanned by the vectors
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\0\\0\\0
\end{bmatrix}
\qquad 
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\1\\0\\0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
is orthogonal to the space spanned by
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\0\\1\\0
\end{bmatrix}
\qquad 
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\0\\0\\1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and thay have no common elements different from $\vec 0$.

Comment: Thanks. I think your sentence should be: "The intersection of two orthogonal subspaces have in common only the zero vector"; isn't it?

Comment: If the two subspaces are orthogonal than, yes, the only common element is the zero vector.